# Taking in a string from a txt file that has prices in double format separated by a tab and putting them into a double array

Tags: java, parsing, file-io

having a parse issue here on bottom line can someone please help!

```
   FileIO io = new FileIO();
            String[] original = io.load("C:\\sharePrice.txt");
            int numcols=original[0].split("\t").length;
            double[]sharePriceArray = new double[numcols];
            for(int i=0;i<numcols;i++)
            { //load in the data
                sharePriceArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(original[i].split("\t"));
            }
```

Comment: Trying to take in data froma txt file that looks like 232   2324  2434   2432 etc. all values separated by a tab. and put them into a double array. I can take it the data to a String array which has a length of 1 but cant seem to split them up and put them in a double array.

Comment: I meant... are you getting an exception? Could you post that?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, .split splits a string into a string array. Your code is trying to assign a double to a string array, so that's the reason of your parse issue.

To fix, I would reccomend splitting the string into an array using .split(), and then traversing that array to assign to the double.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this should be like `original[i].split("\t")[0]`   or `original[i].split("\t")[1]`  in this case you are taking first or second value and then do parsing.